# Django Admin Styling corrupted

Tags: django

I recently made some changes to my django site, one big one being upgrading from Django 2.2 to 3.1. Now my admin site styling is all messed up. I can't figure out what went wrong or how to fix. Any pointers would be appreciated!
See image of what it looks like after update....
The main home page for admin looks fine, but when I click on one of the models to view, the formatted is definitely not correct.
Also, some not all, of my images on the site are saying 404 not found...
[image]

[image]

Comment: you cannot upgrade just by updating django version. django do not support backward comatibility. check on django tutorial.

Comment: Yes you can, I followed this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/upgrade-version/

Comment: Had this exact issue happen in multiple environments. On upgrade from django 2.2+ to 3.2. I was unable to reproduce the issue locally ( ubuntu 20.04, virtuabox win10 ) with firefox, chrome, edge, epiphany. I was unable to repro the issue in our review app, staging, or production environments. 

The person affected by this was in a different part of the country. We disabled all extensions, opened in clean browsers with private windows, incognitos, hard reloaded without cache, separate computers ... the works. However they were still facing the same issue.

Maybe a CDN co-location issue?

Comment: @MattG were you able to find an answer for this?

Comment: @jmunsch I tried a few things and think I got it improved but not completely repaired - I ended up starting a new django project which creates new css for the admin section, I then copied and pasted this into my old project then did collectstatic.

Comment: Did you upgrade from 2.2 to 3.0 then 3.1, or did you jump straight to 3.1? If so I wonder if that was the problem. It's best to upgrade to each major version in step to avoid unexpected upgrade problems.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like your browser is caching the CSS / JS from the old version, you can clear your cache and reload. In chrome use ctrl + shift + r to reload.

Comment: ```ctrl + F5``` worked for me. Btw thanks for the hint of clearing the cache.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same problem, First I thought it was a Cache issue but it wasn't.
I checked the page source and found a css file being applied to the page which wasn't even present on my drive.

In my case the file was:
**static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css**

So I created new file in **static/admin/css** named **nav_sidebar.css**,
then copy pasted the code which I got from page source and
added "display:none;" in the #nav-sidebar section(line:34) and [dir="rtl"] #nav-sidebar section(line:45 in my case).

You can find the Original code here by using Google Chrome's inspect tool.
[Where to find the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWWHv.png)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after bumping django from v3.0 to v3.1. I run `python manage.py collectstatic` to update css which solved my issue

Comment: I ran python manage.py collectstatic as you suggest but the problem persisted until I cleared my browser cache.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same styling as the OP's screenshots.

I had upgraded incrementally from 2.2 -> 3.0 -> 3.1 -> 3.2. I only experienced the styling issues in 3.2

The issue was that there were legacy admin styles committed to the repo in the static folder. To resolve, all I did was delete the committed admin styles, and Django then appeared to use its own styling

Comment: your comment helped a lot. The admin css were overwritten by old legacy files. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was upgrading from 3.0 to 3.2 and I tried a couple of the answers here without luck. At the end, the following procedure solved it for me:

1. manually delete the content of the directory STATIC_ROOT (see in settings.py what you named the folder)
2. run the command `python manage.py collectstatic` This will repopulate the directory with the newst files
3. hard refresh your page (ctrl + F5)

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers here are necessary, but I'll add one more: You might have to bust caches in your server itself. In our example, nginx was configured to provide really long caches to our static files, so we just had to reset it to make changes come through.

Comment: How would you go about clearing the cache in nginx? I'm having this issue now and with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67709529/django-admin-site-nav-sidebar-messed-up

Comment: I think we literally just restarted nginx, but I remember this being stressful.

Comment: do you have any recollection of the steps how you did it? I did all the steps above but it wasn't able to do anything

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not sure.

Comment: Hello, I've tried adding a bounty if that might bring out some attention. I can also provide additional details if there are some information you might need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok maybe I am late to the party but it may help others,
What works for me is:

1. Set `STATIC_ROOT` in settings.py (I guess it should be already there as project is old one)
2. Comment `STATIC_DIR` in `STATICFILES_DIRS` list (otherwise it will give error) and run `python manage.py collectstatic`
3. Clear browser cache.