# django admin site nav sidebar messed up

Tags: python, css, django, sidebar

I recently added a package to my project and did a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` afterwards. I then did `pip install -r requirements.txt` to my local and it added a sidebar.

[image]

I did a `pip install -r requirements.txt` to the server as well and it produced a different result. It's sidebar was messed up.

[image]

I tried removing the sidebar by doing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63811192/12415287) but it did not get removed.

```
.toggle-nav-sidebar {
    z-index: 20;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 0 0 23px;
    width: 23px;
    border: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid var(--hairline-color);
    background-color: var(--body-bg);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: var(--link-fg);
    padding: 0;
    display: none; /*added*/
}

#nav-sidebar {
    z-index: 15;
    flex: 0 0 275px;
    left: -276px;
    margin-left: -276px;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid var(--hairline-color);
    background-color: var(--body-bg);
    overflow: auto;
    display: none; /*added*/
}
```

What should I do to fix this?

If there are any other things I can add to help, do ask.

**ADD** `requirements.txt`:

```
asgiref==3.3.4
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
defusedxml==0.7.1
diff-match-patch==20200713
Django==3.2.3
django-cors-headers==3.7.0
django-filter==2.4.0
django-import-export==2.5.0
django-property-filter==1.1.0
djangorestframework==3.12.4
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
idna==2.10
MarkupPy==1.14
odfpy==1.4.1
openpyxl==3.0.7
python-decouple==3.4
pytz==2019.2
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.25.1
sqlparse==0.3.0
tablib==3.0.0
urllib3==1.26.4
xlrd==2.0.1
xlwt==1.3.0
```

**ADD** sample [github repo](https://github.com/pdarceno/django-prosy-form):

Comment: What new package did you add? If you mean you _upgraded_ Django, then the sidebar was added in Django 3.1. My question then is did you run `collectstatic`? (And potentially some CSS files might be cached too, try `CTRL + F5` (hard refresh))

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I ran `collectstatic` on my live. And I did hard refresh as well. it still is the same

Comment: Try to delete the static folder, then try to do collectstatic again.

Comment: @EPaul i tried this, but it also didn't work

Comment: @ProsyArceno Is it possible for you to provide the requirements.txt contents? As well, before trying that answer, did you add any custom css?

Comment: @NagarajTantri. I added the requirements.txt. I have not added any custom css.

Comment: I think you should share a demo github link of your project

Comment: @ProsyArceno does it also happen the same in incognito window? Very difficult to reproduce this with minimal information. As well, did you check once with your browser's zoom setting?

Comment: @NagarajTantri yes it does happen on incognito.

Comment: @doğukan, I've added the github repo

Comment: But do you want to fix the sidebar or do you want to remove it?

Comment: @MarcCompte, fix. Remove would be an okay solution, but a fix would be best

Comment: Yes, you should aim at fixing it. As a temporary solution check https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html#L73. If you pass a `is_nav_sidebar_enabled` in the context to your AdminSite, you can have it removed the proper way (not with CSS).

Comment: For the actual fix, this looks a lot like there are colliding stylesheets. I guess this is not an option, but if there would be a way for us to check the actual site having problems (the github repo does not produce this result to me), it would be easier to identify the actual problem.

Comment: Try to do this. Go to the production admin site and right click on the nav_bar and select inspect. On the DOM, select exactly the main div (#nav-sidebar) and check the styles applied to it. Try to figure out which one is the one making your sidebar loose its original style. There has to be one overriding the default django style. This will let you identify a little better the problem.

Comment: Then, one possible fix is to eliminate that stylesheet (or the part mentioning the sidebar). Another fix would be to override that yourself by adding a new CSS with a copy of the Django css style and being more specific with your CSS selectors. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, this navbar is added by ***`Django 3.1+`*** and not by any other 3rd part packages.

Copy & Pasting from [Django 3.X admin showing all models in a new navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499212/django-3-x-admin-showing-all-models-in-a-new-navbar),

> From the [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1) [release
> notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/),
>
> > The admin now has a sidebar on larger screens for easier navigation.
> > It is enabled by default but can be disabled by using a custom
> > **AdminSite** and setting [**`AdminSite.enable_nav_sidebar`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.enable_nav_sidebar)
> > to `False`.

So, this is a feature that added in Django 3.1 and can be removed by settings `AdminSite.enable_nav_sidebar = False` (see [How to customize `AdminSite` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class))

---

#### How to fix irregular styling?

You don't have to edit any CSS or HTML file to fix the styling, because Django comes with a new set of CSS and HTML, which *usually* fix the issue. (That is, it is not recommended to alter the styling file *only for this*)

If that doesn't work for you, it might be because of your browser cache.

If you are using Chrome,

1. Go to the admin page
2. `Ctrl + Shift + i` and select `Network` tab and then tick `Disable Cache`
3. Refresh the page
   [image]

Comment: This deserves many many many more likes than it has

Answer (score 15):

see this side bar is added by django 3.1 and it is removable

to remove this you have to add below code in **`admin.py`** or `urls.py` as you are working with admin you should add below code in admin site

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
admin.site.enable_nav_sidebar = False
```

autodiscocer(): This function attempts to import an admin module in each installed application

please let me know if worked

Comment: efficient! and +1 for showing the complete example, including the place to put the code.

Comment: FYI, admin.autodiscover() is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by deleting my static directory, then doing a collect static, then forcing my browser to reload.

This had been caused in a Django 3 to 4 upgrade.